# Python code in sequential processing dependency

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python and struggling with performance issues in one of my code.

I have 2 dataframes(say Df1 and Df2).

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5],
                   'B':['P1','P2','P3','P1','P4','P2','P1','P6','P3','P2','P8'],
                   'C': [1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2,3,2],
                   'D':[100,100,100,200,300,300,400,400,400,500,500],
                   'E':[200,200,200,50,100,100,100,100,100,100,100],
                   'F':[50,50,50,50,150,150,100,100,100,333,333]})

Df2 =pd.DataFrame({'B':['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10'],
                   'L1':[1,4,0,0,2,3,6,56,5,0],
                   'L2':[45,3,0,10,2,4,6,1,6,10],
                   'L3':[0,0,34,10,24,13,19,6,10,10]})
```

What I want to do is process 1 value of A at a time (i.e. always process A=1 before A=2). The reason for doing this is at A=1, I am looking for values of B in Df2 (A=1 has P1,P2 and P3 and I am getting L1,L2 and L3 of P1, P2 and P3 from Df2 by joining Df1 and Df2). Based on some calculation on Values of L1 , L2 ,L3 and C,D,E,F . I am assigning a decision for each row in A=1 as L1 or L2 or L3. For example, Lets say for A=1, the assignment looks like this:

```
Df3= pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1],
                   'B': ['P1','P2','P3'],
                   'C': [1,2,1],
                   'D':[100,100,100],
                   'E':[200,200,200],
                   'F':[50,50,50],
                   'L1':[1,4,0],
                   'L2':[45,3,0],
                   'L3':[0,0,34],
                   'Decision':['L1','L1','L3']})
```

Now since the decision of A=1 is L1,L1 and L3, it will go ahead and subtract value of C from Df2
i.e. it will subtract 1 from Df2 (P1,L1)=1-1=0, subtract 2 from Df2(P2,L1)=4-2=2 and subtract 1 from Df2 (P3,L3)=34-1=33
and hence the updated Df2 will look like:

```
Df2 =pd.DataFrame({'B':['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10'],
                   'L1':[0,2,0,0,2,3,6,56,5,0],
                   'L2':[45,3,0,10,2,4,6,1,6,10],
                   'L3':[0,0,33,10,24,13,19,6,10,10]})
```

And the same cycle is repeated for A=2 and so on. Since the decision of A=1 changed Df2 and thus it changes the outcome of A=2 and so on. I am running loops as of now for each A

I have dataset Df1 in the order of 200 million records with 25 million distinct values of A. Df2 is 0.5 million records. I am running the loop for 25 million times and total runtime is going in the order of 12 days. I tried indexing /faster joins on Df1 and Df2, subsetting Df1 based on some rules but it does not help a lot (it cuts the runtime by 2-3 days only)

Is there any faster way of doing this activity? especially not running loop but still process each value of A sequentially (since previous decision changes future decisions)

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my code below. Although it does not use any for loops up front I don't know if this will help you get past your time constraints. Good Luck!

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="B")
# Your decison maker
import random
def f(x=1):
    return random.choice(['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])

df3["Decision"] = df3.apply(lambda x: f(x),axis=1)
df3.sort_values(by='A').reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

def ff(x):
    global df2
    df2.loc[df2.B == x.B, x.Decision] -= x.C
    return 

a = df3[["B", "Decision", "C"]].apply(lambda x: ff(x), axis=1)

df2
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do tell if this makes it any easier for 200 million records (I'd give myself a pat on the back :P)